# How do I add pcie_aspm=force to my boot options?

Tags: 11.10, boot, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

I just upgraded to 11.10 from 11.04 on my laptop (I don't have Windows) by downloading from the Ubuntu website.  The laptop battery is in bad condition, but I was using it with the 11.04 plugged to AC all the time, and everything was fine.

After installing 11.10, the laptop seems to not notice that it is connected to AC, so it shuts down a few minutes after starting.  I read that I have to type `pcie_aspm=force` in the boot command, so I tried accessing it by pressing the "F6" key while booting, and then the other F keys, but nothing happened. I also found that I can write that instruction in the terminal window, but I don't know in which file or location. I would appreciate some help, but I am not a computer engineer, so please write the instructions in plain English.

Answer (score 14):

To apply it to all kernels, edit `/etc/default/grub` (root privileges required) and change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

Run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

To edit the boot options on startup, hold <kbd>Esc</kbd> while starting GRUB (after the BIOS POST). Press <kbd>E</kbd> on the selected entry, use your arrows to move and keyboard to type. When done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

Comment: Thanks Lekensteyn.  I edited the _DEFAULT line as you wrote, but I didn't find how to run the "sudo update-grub". However, I could save the edited file by pressing CTRL O (like "Oscar") which I found in the Help of the Terminal as the command to save changed files. But it didn't work, the laptop continues not noticing that it is connected to the wall outlet. Seems like there is a setting telling it to run from the battery only (cable was OK 5 days ago). But I didn't try to put the "pcie_aspm..." before the "quiet splash". Please help, it only runs for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In the linked question below, the OP asked a similar question - in their case they wanted to add *nomodeset* to GRUB.

You could use the same advice given but substitute *nomodeset* for *pcie_aspm=force*

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834)

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom.  I edited the _DEFAULT line as you wrote, but I didn't find how to run the "sudo update-grub". However, I could save the edited file by pressing CTRL O (like "Oscar") which I found in the Help of the Terminal as the command to save changed files. But it didn't work, the laptop continues not noticing that it is connected to the wall outlet. Seems like there is a setting telling it to run from the battery only (cable was OK 5 days ago). But I didn't try to put the "pcie_aspm..." before the "quiet splash". Please help, it only runs for 5 minutes.

Comment: I doubt that pcie_aspm will work.  I would use a boot option such as "acpi=off" to turn off power management.  Run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

One-line solution, use at you own risk:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"\(.*\)\"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"\1 pcie_aspm=force\"/' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```