# How to install this kernel?

Tags: 11.10, kernel, power-management

I have a Samsung notebook with Core i3 Sandy Bridge processor and I want to install the patched kernel available here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement

What Kernel version should I install, Oneiric Ocelot or Precise Pangolin?

What packages should I install? And how should I install them (the easiest way possible, please)?

Additional info: Ubuntu 11.10 x64 with Kernel 3.0.0-14.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the link you will find a number of *deb* packages, that should contain the patched kernel.
The easiest way to install deb package on Ubuntu is:

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Just download amd64 versions of [those packages](http://zinc.canonical.com/~cking/powermanagement/mjgaspmfix/oneiric/). Please note that you may want both kernel image and it's headers.

P.S. 11.10 = Oneiric Ocelot

Comment: This will replace the Kernel currently installed and remove the previous?

Comment: No. It will install new kernel keeping the old one.

Comment: I have installed the Kernel with ASPM fix, but it doesn't make any difference on the battery duration. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously wouldn't bother with the kernel as you can get the biggest power saving just by [editing your grub configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68372/how-do-i-add-pcie-aspm-force-to-my-boot-options). Really this alone was very effective for me on our Samsung laptop (2.5 hours to 4-5 hours).

And by not using a non-standard kernel it means:

- You'll get security updates automatically.
- You're not running on untested software.

Comment: Are you sure this is safe? I read in the comments of one post in OMG Ubuntu that apparently this damages the battery in some cases. Here's the link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/linux-power-regression-overheating-problem-on-thinkpad-fixed/

Comment: Three people out of hundreds whose batteries started to lose capacity. I've had no problems which is not to say there isn't a problem, just that if it does exist, it hasn't affect me. If it did exist I would be *very* surprised if it couldn't be fixed by some proper power-cycling. It's quite hard to do permanent damage to a battery by just pulling and pushing current.

Comment: I tried the pcie_aspm=force with Grub, according to powertop without it the consumption was 16.4W and with ASPM enabled 15.8W. The difference was minimal.