# Laptop overheats when running Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 64-bit, overheating, amd-processor, gallium

I've been away from Ubuntu since introduction of the Unity interface.  When 13.10 was released I figured I'd give it another shot and installed it on my HP G62.  This laptop has an AMD V120 cpu and a Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 gpu.  I've also got 6gb ram installed and am using the original HDD.

My laptop overheats so much, I have to regularly turn it off and wait for a while before continuing to use it. The bottom surface is so hot that I cannot let it touch my leg and the top surface is getting almost too hot to touch, too.  I even noticed that the laptop is now producing a very hot smell that is really concerning me.

I've tried several things I've read here on AaskUbuntu like editing `/etc/default/grub` to use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux quiet splash"`.  I've installed **FWTS** along with a few other utilities to no avail.

This **computer does not run very hot when using** windows 7 or **any other gnu/linux distros** including Ubuntu derivatives.

If anybody could please suggest another option or inform me that I should use another OS, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `pcie_aspm=force` might help. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/68383/75166) is how to do it. Does it help? Also [tlp](http://askubuntu.com/a/285681/75166) is recommended.

Comment: Did you find an answer or solution to your problem? I'm running an HP laptop with AMD CPU as well, and i have the same problem you do. Right now, I'm using Chrome, terminal and Psensor is telling me 75+ degrees.

Answer (score 0):

How much resources do you use in system-monitor. i think the unity-surface is very high in consumption. perhaps thy same ubuntu with diffrent surface? (e.G. lxde? / Kde?)

Comment: Okay, so I didn't particularly want to resort to installing alternative desktop environments.  But, I did anyway.  I've installed lxde, kde, and openbox.  It's still crazy hot.  Even when I'm only using gedit and chromium in openbox, this sucker is blazing. When the system was using the unity interface, my computer was using slightly more than %30 cpu idling, in lxde it was upper teens.  So, there was a considerable improvement there.  But, this is still too hot and if I'm going to continue using this laptop, I'm going to have to install a different system on it unless I can find a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try indicator-cpufreq or TLP.  Should also install a temperature indicator like Xsensors.  I imagine that you have check your fans are working and have cleaned out the dust and dirt.  Indicator-cpufreq works similar to the jupiter applet.